# How can I delete all my available receipts in my Concur profile at once?

Tags: untagged

I couldn't find the option. I looked at:

1. https://www.concursolutions.com/Expense/Client/default.asp:

[image]

2. https://www.concursolutions.com/Expense/Client/default.asp -> expense report -> click on one expense

[image]

I couldn't find any info on Google. https://sapconcur.psu.edu/faq/how-do-i-delete-attached-receipts only deals with receipts that are attached to a report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Concur Travel Expense Project Manager Alessandro Munari](https://community.concur.com/t5/Concur-Expense/How-can-I-delete-all-my-available-receipts-in-my-Concur-profile/m-p/17346/emcs_t/S2h8ZW1haWx8bWVudGlvbl9zdWJzY3JpcHRpb258S09YWVpFNFdZVjgyTjZ8MTczNDZ8QVRfTUVOVElPTlN8aEs#M6432), this is currently not possible:

> it would be an interesting feature to have, but at the moment, once you uploaded pictures the only way to remove those is to select them one by one